# How can i install a package in conda? the library version issue

Tags: conda

I have a problem when i tried to install a package.
*CentOS7

1. In my server, glibc version is 2.17 (`ldd--version command`)
2. using `module load anaconda`
3. `conda env create -f RoseTTAFold-linux.yml`

---

```
Collecting package metadata: done

Solving environment: failed

ResolvePackageNotFound:

    - libstdccxx-ng==9.3.0=hd4cf53a_17 -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']

    - libgcc-ng==9.3.0=hd5101ec6_17 -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
```

---

How can I install the package?

Thank you.